# how to find maximum rows limitation and how to change it, in mysql table InnoDB?

Tags: mysql

How to find maximum number of row in single mysql table with innoDb engine.

I have audit table, Aprox 400k records entry in it.
when i trying to count record or open audit table, it says table is empty. 
is there any table row limitation reach? if yes, then how to change it to maximum

My current Table status:

```
Auto Increment value : 645045
Data length : 50256 
Row : 465735
```

Comment: `400000` records should not create an issue. Thats not a big amount data, check if the table is corrupt or you are in the right DB.

Comment: I am in right DB, but when i am trying to truncate or delete table , entire DB stuck . so i assume that table is corrupt  only? because other table works correctly

Comment: you may first try `repair table table_name quick` and see if this fixes the issue. Truncate is faster than delete since while you delete records and if there is a logging system on then for each deleted record it would log the data and for large data set its really slow.